# Getting results from many async db queries

Tags: mongodb, asynchronous

I need to iterate over an array of users and get information about each one from the database. I am trying to use the async library's map function, but i can't get it to accept my iterator. I have something like this:

```
async.map(arr, getInfo(id), function(err, results){
    // do stuff with the results
}

getInfo(id, callback){
   db.myCollection.find({query: params}, {projections: true}, function(err, info){
   callback(err, info)
   })
}
```

I'm getting iterator(x.value, function (err, v) {
                ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function

among other errors while trying different things. Basically, I need a data structure with the responses from the db in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be 100% sure we'd need to see your array and data. However from the code you've pasted it looks like you're passing the function in the wrong way.

you passing a function that already receives some parameter?
I'm assuming your array contains ids so you should pass the function in the right way to map:

Change:

```
async.map(arr, getInfo(id), function(err, results)
                       ^^^
```

into:

```
async.map(arr, getInfo, function(err, results){
```

Comment: yea, that took care of it. I'm still a bit confused about how to operate on the data inside getInfo. Do I just treat it like the function is being called once with each object in the array being used as a param? Is there a need to return the desired result from getInfo or is somehow automatic?

Comment: also, the db queries are all async, so do I return from inside the db query callback or at the end of getInfo?

Comment: map waits for all the function in the array, so you must call the callback after each record is processed (either success or fail). And your function should be exactly as if it's operating on one record (as that is what it's actually doing). Also if this worked, I'd appreciate it if you accept it as the answer. Thanks!